# How to convert plain text [Already know the alignment, font,size] to a RTF text using C#

Tags: c#, rtf

I am in need to convert the plain text to a RTF text. I know the font ,size, alignment of the plain text. What i want is how to convert to the preformatted RTF text without using `RichTextBox` control in windows forms, because i am going to implement this in a class library for 5 platforms.

Comment: Do you have the RTF specification?

Answer (score 1):

I found this promising looking RTF writer:

http://netrtfwriter.sourceforge.net/